# -[UIDeviceRGBColor red]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, uicolor, unrecognized-selector

`CGFloat colorR = color.red;`

It worked for a few builds, but then I modified some code that has nothing to do with `color` and suddenly that line crashes my app every time I try to run through it, even after undoing those changes.

```
NSLog(@"%@", color.CGColor);
    //<CGColor %p> [<CGColorSpace %p> (kCGColorSpaceDeviceRGB)] ( 0.2 0.5 0.7 1 )
NSLog(@"%f", color.red);
    //-[UIDeviceRGBColor red]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Is the availability and (rare) correct function of `color.red` a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-red is no public instance method for UIColor. UIColors could be represented in any color space and some conversion might be involved. To read the raw RGB components from a UIColor object you must use the method:
 `- (BOOL)getRed:(CGFloat *)red green:(CGFloat *)green blue:(CGFloat *)blue alpha:(CGFloat *)alpha`

I don't know why color.red sometimes works - it could be that certain colors use one of the class cluster instances internally with that method and other times they are stored in another format.

Comment: So getting a float for `color.red` definitely is a bug? Why am I allowed try, though?

Comment: @Thromordyn in your code yes :) Not an apple bug as the interface was never public

Comment: `UIColor-Expanded` allows for `color.red` but I guess I plugged it in wrong. Your option requires all of one more line, so I'll just stick with that.